# Variations of Kinematic equations

Tags: kinematics, notation, differentiation

So I recently decided to start learning physics, and have been using various online resources to learn. What I always find are different ways to write the same equation. Now I realize this might be a stupid question, but here I go. I understand the equation for velocity is v=s/t, but I’ve also seen v=s/(delta t), and a few more. And for acceleration, I find variants which included initial/final velocities/times, I find deltas in some equations and sometimes I don’t. I just really need clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Delta ($\Delta$) is simply a symbol that represents *change*. So, instead of writing **Final Velocity - Initial Velocity**, we can simply write $\Delta V$ to represent the change in velocity (or vice versa). Same for acceleration, position, and time.

However, note that kinematic equations can only be used when acceleration is constant, which is why we can use: 
$$a = \frac{\Delta V}{\Delta T}$$
This formula implies that the velocity changed linearly with the time.

Later, when you apply calculus to physics, the derivative of velocity function to is used for solving for the variable acceleration (and same with velocity, position, etc.), so you will see yet another format/version of the formulas, that look like this:

$$a = \frac{dv}{dt}$$

Comment: Thank you, but what do you mean by constant acceleration? As in 2 m/s/s and it doesn’t change? Also, for the definition of acceleration, is it a=(delta v)/(delta t), and a=v/t? Also, what is instantaneous velocity?

Comment: Yes, constant acceleration means it doesn't change. Different texts may use either one of the formulas, but the correct one is the one with delta, because we are dealing with change. Instantaneous velocity is the velocity at an instant in time (not delta T, which is a range of time), and calculus is usually used to find this. I recommend watching videos on Khan Academy for this unit, it's really helpful to understand the basic ideas first. Then, if you still have unanswered questions, post them here and we'll help. Good luck :)

Comment: Ok, just to make sure I got the hang of this: Average Velocity: V=(delta s)/(delta t), instantaneous velocity: V= (s)/(delta t), constant acceleration: a=v/t, non constant acceleration (what is the proper term for this?): a=(delta v)/(delta t)

Comment: No, both formulas (the ones with delta and the ones without) are the same, but the delta one is the technically correct one. Average velocity is delta s/ delta t. Average acceleration is delta v/delta t. The key word here is "average". You can still use the formula for non-constant  acceleration, but you will get the average acceleration during that period of time (delta t), and same for velocity. Instantaneous velocity and acceleration involves using a derivative. So instantaneous velocity is ds/dt and instantaneous acceleration is dv/dt.

Comment: Is acceleration also a=(delta v)/ t?

Comment: It’s just so confusing because some other formulas require a=delta v/ t, and others a=delta v/ delta t. Same thing with velocity

Comment: Think about it this way: acceleration, by definition, is a change in velocity during a period of time. Therefore, because we are dealing with a change in v and change in t, we can use the symbol delta. So a = delta v/ delta t. This is the correct formula. If you only write delta v/ t, you're saying "change in velocity over time", but how much time? To write how much time, we write delta t. Same with v. Correct formula is delta s/delta t. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that what I was thinking, but for the formula Vf=Vi + at, you need to use a=delta v/ t. I just want to make sure I’m using the right formulas for the right situations.